# NSTimer & Selector

Tags: swift

So not sure what I'm doing wrong - been banging my head for a while and yes I have looked at quite a lot of other SO questions and tried lots of things but haven't been able to sort this out.

I'm trying to use NSTimer:

```
var x = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: "timeToMoveOn", userInfo: nil, repeats: false);
```

my selector function is:

```
func timeToMoveOn()
{
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil);
}
```

but what ever I do I keep getting this error 'Extra argument 'selector' in call.

I've tried things like scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval but get the same error.  I've cleaned and rebuilt the project and just can't seem to get it to work.

What am I missing?

Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 0):

okay, I solved my own problem...
I was accidentally declaring the var x timmer as a class member rather than within a function.  Once I added it to viewDidLoad it worked fine.  Interesting that selectors don't seem to work in class member scope.